# find minimum pattern in string using perl expression

Tags: perl

i am trying to find minimum pattern in a ( 2 char ) string examples :

```
enter code here

 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use warnings;
 use strict;


 my $str1;
 $str1 = 'abbabbabbabbabb'; #  abb is repeating  
 $str1 = 'abababababababa';  #  ab is repeating 
 $str1 = 'abaaaabaaaabaaa';  #  abaaa is repeating
 $str1 = 'bbaabbaabbaabbaa'; #  bbaa is repeating
```

it its always 2 chars 'a' and 'b' and there is always a pattern , 
no corner cases of 'a' or 'b' only.
any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks    Michael

Answer (score 6):

```
my ($repeated_pattern) = $str1 =~ /^(.+?)\1+\z/s;
```